# Put all function that are in a header file in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

is there any way to put all to functions that are in a header file in a namespace, without change the header itself?
for example, if I have a header file called "funcs.h" which has some functions inside, is there any way to put all the functions inside in a namespace without changing "funcs.h"?

Thank you!

Comment: there is a way, but before writing an answer... why would you? If you do not modify the header you can include it inside the namespace or outside, thats a sure source of bugs and problems

Comment: What kind of functions? The is also a funcs.cpp?

Comment: This is not a good idea. If you're using a library that was designed to be used without namespaces, adding namespaces is a non-trivial change. If you're running into name conflicts, bite the bullet and rewrite the library. In the long run, that will be much simpler than trying to code around a design error.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was some dirty hacks, but there is no reason to use a hack.

Suppose you have a function defined in global scope (actually I use an overload set for the example, and whether this is inside a header or not is not relevant):

```
void foo() {}
void foo(int) {}
```

You can make it accessible from within a namespace via `using`:

```
namespace ns {
    using ::foo;
}

int main() {
    ns::foo();
    ns::foo(1);
}
```

Just be aware that you now have `ns::foo` and `::foo` both refering to the same function (set of overloads, resp.).